# What is the -- t/ means in git?

Tags: git

I am reading the git documentation and came across this command

```
git log --pretty="%h - %s" --author='Junio C Hamano' --since="2008-10-01" \
--before="2008-11-01" --no-merges -- t/
```

I tried searching the document itself and the internet but could not find out what -- t/ at the end of the command means. Could anybody help?

Comment: It's filtering the output to *only* show commits modifying said path (`t/`). The `--` option means "everything past this is to be considered as paths". Doc [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---ltpathgt82308203).

Answer (score 2):

You say "I am reading the git documentation." Well, [the documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) (on `git log`) *tells* you the answer. It says, right at the start, that the form of the `git log` command is:

> ```
> git log [<options>] [<revision range>] [[--] <path>…​]
> ```

Which tells you that you may optionally append at the end of your `git log` command a `--` followed by a `path`. And `path` is explained later in the same documentation:

> ```
> [--] <path>…​
> ```
>
> Show only commits that are enough to explain how the files that match the specified paths came to be.

So `-- t/` means: Don't log *all* the commits; log only the commits that involve changes in the files in the `t` directory.

Comment: Thank you, I should have said the pro git book instead of documentation.

Comment: Yes, they are certainly different things. The real documentation is always the place to look for this sort of information.